# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, ora-00907

I need to know why I get a parenthesis error in this part of the code.

```
CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
COD_CIUDAD NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT CIUDAD_PK PRIMARY KEY (COD_CIUDAD),
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_REGION VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_REGION NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I rolled back your last edit and restored the original question. Do not change your question to something else once you have an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using an in-line constraint, the `PRIMARY KEY` automatically refers to the column being declared.  Hence, the `(COD_CIUDAD)` is not accepted.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE CIUDAD (
    COD_CIUDAD NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT CIUDAD_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_REGION VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_REGION NOT NULL
);
```

I changed the type of `NOMBRE_REGION` to `VARCHAR2()`.

Comment: good answer, i upvoted but  the type of `NOMBRE_REGION` was already `VARCHAR2`, wasn't it?

Comment: @Derezed If this answer solved your issue, you have to accept it, just click on the mark below the voting arrows. And it is good to visit the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more

Comment: I have another problem

Comment: @Derezed . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not by editing already answered questions or in comments.

Answer (score 1):

*When using `PRIMARY KEY (COD_CIUDAD)` syntax, then constraint must be defined separately from the column or remove `(COD_CIUDAD)`*

You should use the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
COD_CIUDAD NUMBER(3) ,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20)  CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_REGION VARCHAR(20)  CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_REGION NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CIUDAD_PK PRIMARY KEY (COD_CIUDAD)
);
```

Also you can ignore naming `NOT NULL` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
COD_CIUDAD NUMBER(3) ,
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(20)  NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_REGION VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CIUDAD_PK PRIMARY KEY (COD_CIUDAD)
);
```

*References:*

- [Oracle / PLSQL: Primary Keys](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php)
- [Oracle / PLSQL: CREATE TABLE Statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table.php)

Comment: @Derezed i posted an answer in the question that you asked related to this problem. and i am waiting to your reply